# Query to match tables based on ref_id and find total billed_amount according to city_names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

First table T1 contains three columns:

- City_names
- Ref_id
- Date

T1 consists of 60 rows

Second table T2 contains three columns:

- Ref_id
- Billed_Amount
- Sale_Price

T2 consist of 13 rows

The Ref_id column in both tables have some common values. I need to match the Ref_id values of T2 with the City_names of T1. Also find the total Billed_Amount and total Sale_price according to City_names

How to write an SQL query for this (using SQL Server):

1. If both tables are in same database
2. If tables are in different databases in same server

Please help

Comment: @DaleK
I tried left join  T2 and T1  on T2.Ref_id = T1.Ref_id

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt to join the table by Ref_id is probably not wrong. The final query might look something like this:

```
SELECT T1.City_Name, SUM(T2.Billed_Amount) as BilledAmount, SUM(T2.Sale_Price) as SalePrice
FROM [DATABASE_1_NAME_HERE].[SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME_1_HERE] as T1 LEFT JOIN
    [DATABASE_2_NAME_HERE].[SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME_2_HERE]  as T2 on T1.Ref_id = T2.Ref_id
GROUP BY T1.City_Name
```

You additionally need to group by city name and simultaneously sum up the billed amount and the sales prices.

If the tables are on the same database you can leave out the "[DATABASE_NAME_HERE].[SCHEMA_NAME]." part.

Comment: Hey thank you ! 
as you mentioned I used group by but for that i had to use this as a sub query . Anyways ,  found the solution, thanks!